# Left Join not displaying rows containing null values in Joomla but fine in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, joomla, null, left-join

Been slamming my head against the wall for well over a day - hoping someone can shed some light on this.

I've ran this in phpmyadmin, no problem.
Run it in Joomla, won't return any records if there's a null value.

(overview)
I'm developing a component in the backend where a manager can check off if a particular provider has completed certain requirements.  The requirements are stored in the Questions table (and they are categorized into multiple Mods) while the provider records are stored in the Providers table.  Soon this will be linked from one big table that shows all the users, click on the user and get this table with appropriate checkboxes for each question to check off whether or not they completed it.

Here's the structure:

Questions Table:
question_id  question_mod question_description

Providers Table:
provider_id  provider_userid  question_id  provider_passedchk

MySQL query (works as expected):

```
SELECT p.provider_id
    , p.provider_userid     
    , q.question_mod
    , q.question_id
    , p.question_id                 
    , q.question_description
    , p.provider_passedchk
FROM `jos_assess_questions` AS q
LEFT JOIN `jos_assess_providers` AS p ON q.question_id = p.question_id  AND p.provider_userid =40
WHERE q.question_mod = 1
ORDER BY p.provider_userid

LIMIT 0,1000
```

In Joomla (in the model, returns an empty table):

```
public function getListQuery()
{
        $query = parent::getListQuery();
        $question_mod = JRequest::getVar('modID');
        $userId = JRequest::getVar('userID');

        $db =& JFactory::getDBO();          
        $query = $db->getQuery(true);

        $query->SELECT('p.provider_id
        , p.provider_userid     
        , q.question_mod
        , q.question_id
        , p.question_id                 
        , q.question_description
        , p.provider_passedchk                                      
        , p.published
        ');
        $query->FROM (' #__assess_questions AS q');
        $query->LEFTJOIN (' #__assess_providers AS p ON q.question_id = p.question_id AND p.provider_userid='.$userId.'');
        $query->WHERE ('q.question_mod = '.$question_mod.'');
        $query->ORDERBY (' p.provider_userid');
               $db->setQuery($query);   

return $query;

}
```

Any ideas?  Thanks!

Comment: are you sure there is no error in the query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turn on Debug profiling so you can see exactly what queries are being executed.

Once you find the specific query in the profiler, run it in phpMyAdmin, and see if you get the same result.

If you *do* get the same result, examine how you are displaying the data, as that will likely be where the issue exists.

Comment: You're awesome - there was a WHERE statement from a different section that was messing up the works on the Joomla side.  Thank you!!